# How to make node delete confirmation inline?

Tags: 7, nodes

I need to know how to override the normal delete node confirmation (preferably for a specific content type). My site has one content type that users are able to delete and right now it forward them to an unstyled /delete/ page to do so.

I'd like the same functionality but with an inline delete confirmation on that content type, ideally without additional modules.

Edit: Just realized I would have to manage permissions to account for deleting the content. May need to do it directly bypassing regular methods

Comment: I can't think of a way you could do this without adding a module (or at least adding code to an existing custom module).

Comment: The latter is ok with me.. however in the meantime I've realized it will probably be better for me to unpublish it via a custom query

Comment: Or if you want to delete it permanently you can just call `node_delete($nid);`

Answer (score 2):

you can put this in your `node--node-type.tpl.php` file:

```
$item = menu_get_item("node/$nid/delete");
if ($item['access']) {
    include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'node') . '/node.pages.inc');
    $page_title = drupal_get_title();
    $delete_form = drupal_get_form('node_delete_confirm', $node);
    print render($delete_form);
    drupal_set_title($page_title, PASS_THROUGH);
}
```

also you can remove `Cancel` link from $delete_form

Comment: just for clarification. Would this bypass the slandered delete confirmation page for all delete functions?